# How to pass data-plugin="timepicker" value to controller in angularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have code to pass date and time to controller.

Here is HTML code,

```
<div class="page-content" ng-app="app">
   <div ng-controller="postAppoinmentCtr as ctrl" class="panel-body">
       <form ng-submit="submitForm()" id="form1">

            <input name="time" ng-model="time" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="time" data-plugin="timepicker" autocomplete="off"/>
            <input name="date" ng-model="date" type="text" class="form-control" data-plugin="datepicker"/>
            <input..ng-model="type"...></input>
            <input..ng-model="Description"...></input>
            <button ...>
       </form>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is angular js part

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('postAppoinmentCtr', function($scope, $http, $location) {

$scope.submitForm = function(){
    var url = $location.absUrl() + "/addAppoinment";
    alert(url);

    var config = {
        headers : {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
        }
    }

    var data = {
        type: $scope.type,
        date: $scope.date,
        time: $scope.time,
        description: $scope.description
    };


    $http.post(url, data, config).then(function (response) {
        $scope.postResultMessage = "Sucessful!";
    }, function (response) {
        $scope.postResultMessage = "Fail!";
    });

    $scope.type = "";
    $scope.date = "";
    $scope.time ="";
    $scope.description ="";
}
});
```

When click the button type and description pass to controller. But date and time not. I can do this using

```
<input id="date-birth" class="form-control" type="date" ng-model="date">
```

this line. But I need to use `data-plugin="datepicker"` .
I'm new one for the angularjs and I try to many ways for solve  this problem.
Please give me some answer this. Thanks in advance.